# How do I pass a command line argument to a service container?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to set up a bitbucket pipeline that uses a database service provided by a docker container. However, in order to get the database service started correctly, I need to pass an argument to be received by the database container's ENTRYPOINT. I see from the [pipeline service doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/#TestwithdatabasesinBitbucketPipelines-image-with-db) that it's possible to send `variables` to the service's docker container, but the option I need to set isn't settable by an environment variable, only by a command line argument.

When I run the database's docker image locally using `docker run`, I am able to set the option just by adding it to the end of the `docker run` command, and it gets correctly applied to the container's ENTRYPOINT, so it seems like this should be straightforward, I just can't figure out where to put the argument in bitbucket-pipelines.yml.

Below is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml. Everything about it works great except that I need a way to pass a command line argument to the victoria-metrics container at the end of the file.

```
image: node:14.16.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
        services:
          - mongo
          - victoriaMetrics

definitions:
  services:
    mongo:
      image: mongo:3.6
    victoriaMetrics:
      image: victoriametrics/victoria-metrics:v1.75.1
```

Comment: Can you post your whole pipeline? Is your variable dynamic? How will you run your pipeline?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun, sure, question updated to include the full bitbucket-pipelines.yml The option I need to pass is not dynamic, it will be the same every time. My pipeline is being run automatically when a commit is pushed to bitbucket. Overall, the pipeline has been working and running well for some time with just the mongo service. The problem now is that I need to add the victoriaMetrics service and need to be able to pass it a command line argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Mark C from Atlassian, there is presently [no way to pass command line arguments to service containers](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-pass-an-argument-to-a-service-container-in-a-bitbucket/qaq-p/1988143). However, he has created a [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21810) for this capability, which you are welcome to vote for if interested.

In the meantime, the suggested workarounds are:

> 1. You can start the service container by running a Docker command within Pipelines as long as the command is not restricted.
>    You can check [this link](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#Full-list-of-restricted-commands) for more information about Docker restricted commands on Pipelines.
> 2. You can create your own Docker image (using Dockerfile) and upload it to Docker Hub then use that image as a service container on Pipelines

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - ...
          - docker run -d --rm -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all
          - ...
        services:
          - ...
          - docker
          - ...
```

Comment: Thanks @scarperharper. I think this is an example of workaround #1 from my answer ("running a Docker command within Pipelines"), right?

Comment: Absolutely @mactyr - just thought a cut-and-paste example might be useful :-)